# How to align scale descriptions?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

In the picture below, I've aligned the Low and High scale descriptions over the first and 7th option. I've done this in bootstrap by trying to create elements with styles that match the scale as closely as possible on the row that contains the scale descriptions and then centering the "Low" and "High" over their respective numbers.

Unfortunately, you can see that "High" isn't aligned as well as I'd like. And while I can fix this for one screen size, it doesn't hold for other screen sizes. I could, of course, come up with specialized styles to account for all breakpoints but I really need a more versatile solution as I will eventually need to have more descriptions than just the two. And I will likely need to stagger them over two rows.

I am open to any solution, but the one that seems the most straightforward to me would be something where I could simply calculate an absolute position in javscript/jQuery. Take the first option and find it's center on both axis, then subtract from that to find the center of the text I'd like to place. Then I'm not certain from there... I might need to actually find the width of the displayed description and then subtract half?

As I am writing this, it occurs to me that because I am using bootstrap, maybe I could dynamically adjust the class on the parent element to cover the same number of columns as there are options (in this example, 7). Perhaps this is the best solution? I suppose I will go try it after I finish writing this question... but because this may not be the best answer and because I feel I've already spent enough time/effort on this, I'm still going to post my question in case there is a better answer!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how flexible those circle indicators should be, but perhaps something like this can help you out:

```
<style>
    .circle-row {
        margin-top: 20px; /*needed for label*/
    }
    .circle {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .circle:not(:first-child) {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .circle-row .circle:first-child:after,
    .circle-row .circle:last-child:after {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        top: -20px; /*needed for label*/
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        word-break: keep-all;
    }
    .circle-row .circle:first-child:after {
        content: 'low';
    }
    .circle-row .circle:last-child:after {
        content: 'high long label';
    }
</style>

<div class="circle-row">
    <div class="circle"><span>1</span></div>
    <div class="circle"><span>2</span></div>
    <div class="circle"><span>3</span></div>
    <div class="circle"><span>4</span></div>
    <div class="circle"><span>5</span></div>
    <div class="circle"><span>6</span></div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0foyL3g1/

With this CSS we inject labels to first and last circle. Labels are positioned absolute, so we add fixed width (100px) if we want label to be wider than .circle (20px).